# Group by key in crossfilter data in table structure. I do not need the chart

Tags: crossfilter

I have a large set of records over 5 million. I have managed to pull the data as json using crossfilter in table structure. Now I want to group the data using symbol key. Any help will be appreciated.

Here is my code

```
    d3.json("my_json_file.json", function(error, json_data) {
        var data = crossfilter(json_data),
        typeDimension = stocks_jsoncs.dimension(function (d) {
            return d.symbol;
        });
        typeGroup = typeDimension.group().all();
        $('#stk_table').dataTable({
            "aaData": typeDimension.top(Infinity),
                "aoColumns": [{
                "mDataProp": "id"
            }, {
                "mDataProp": "symbol"
            }, {
                "mDataProp": "stock_name"
            }, {
                "mDataProp": "changepercent"
            }, {
                "mDataProp": "close"
            }, {
                "mDataProp": "volume"
            }]
        });
    });
```

Here are few content of my json file:

```
    [{"id":"11","symbol":"01KG","stock_name":"Scottish American Investment Co. PLC","changepercent":"0","close":"125.00","volume":"0"},{"id":"63","symbol":"01KG","stock_name":"Scottish American Investment Co. PLC","changepercent":"0","close":"125.00","volume":"0"},{"id":"64","symbol":"01OO","stock_name":"Nordic Investment Bank 5.25% Nts 26\/11\/19","changepercent":"-0.532","close":"118.30","volume":"2000"},{"id":"65","symbol":"01OO","stock_name":"Nordic Investment Bank 5.25% Nts 26\/11\/19","changepercent":"-0.264","close":"118.93","volume":"6000"},{"id":"66","symbol":"01OO","stock_name":"Nordic Investment Bank 5.25% Nts 26\/11\/19","changepercent":"0.602","close":"119.25","volume":"7000"},{"id":"67","symbol":"01OO","stock_name":"Nordic Investment Bank 5.25% Nts 26\/11\/19","changepercent":"1.747","close":"118.53","volume":"3000"},{"id":"68","symbol":"01OO","stock_name":"Nordic Investment Bank 5.25% Nts 26\/11\/19","changepercent":"0","close":"116.50","volume":"10000000"},{"id":"69","symbol":"04LL","stock_name":"British Land Company PLC","changepercent":"0","close":"115.00","volume":"0"},{"id":"132","symbol":"06GH","stock_name":"Barclays Bank Plc 9% Perm Int Brg Cap Bds #","changepercent":"0.8","close":"126.00","volume":"0"},{"id":"159","symbol":"06GH","stock_name":"Barclays Bank Plc 9% Perm Int Brg Cap Bds #","changepercent":"0.412","close":"122.00","volume":"0"},{"id":"160","symbol":"06GH","stock_name":"Barclays Bank Plc 9% Perm Int Brg Cap Bds #","changepercent":"0","close":"121.50","volume":"0"},{"id":"179","symbol":"06GH","stock_name":"Barclays Bank Plc 9% Perm Int Brg Cap Bds #","changepercent":"0","close":"119.50","volume":"0"},{"id":"180","symbol":"06GH","stock_name":"Barclays Bank Plc 9% Perm Int Brg Cap Bds #","changepercent":"-3.239","close":"119.50","volume":"6000"},{"id":"181","symbol":"06GH","stock_name":"Barclays Bank Plc 9% Perm Int Brg Cap Bds #","changepercent":"0","close":"123.50","volume":"0"},{"id":"191","symbol":"06GH","stock_name":"Barclays Bank Plc 9% Perm Int Brg Cap Bds #","changepercent":"0","close":"121.50","volume":"0"},{"id":"192","symbol":"06GH","stock_name":"Barclays Bank Plc 9% Perm Int Brg Cap Bds #","changepercent":"0","close":"121.50","volume":"0"},{"id":"193","symbol":"06GH","stock_name":"Barclays Bank Plc 9% Perm Int Brg Cap Bds #","changepercent":"0","close":"121.50","volume":"0"},{"id":"194","symbol":"06GH","stock_name":"Barclays Bank Plc 9% Perm Int Brg Cap Bds #","changepercent":"0","close":"121.50","volume":"0"},{"id":"195","symbol":"06HB","stock_name":"Hemingway Debenture LD","changepercent":"0","close":"130.00","volume":"0"},{"id":"228","symbol":"06HB","stock_name":"Hemingway Debenture LD","changepercent":"0","close":"130.00","volume":"0"}]
```

Comment: 5 million records is too much. What are you trying to do here? If you just want to display in a table, then there is no reason to use Crossfilter.

Comment: I need to filter the data using crossfilter as it is much faster as compared the mysql filter for 5 million records. I managed to pull the records in the table format but I am not able to group the data by a key.